# Findind array in an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to search array values in key of associative array and then make and array of key values. I a using in_array() func to search but i can use foreach func for one array.

This is my code, but the issue is it asks me for string and I gave array.

```
function getrarity(){
$json = '{"cards":[
        {
            "card_verify_id":"1",
            "name":"cardname1",
            "rarity":"1"
        },
        {
            "card_verify_id":"2",
            "name":"cardname2",
            "rarity":"2"
        }]
}';
$card = array(1, 2);
$cards = json_decode($json);
$commons = array();

foreach($cards->cards as $items) {
    if(in_array($card, $items->card_verify_id)){
        $commons[] = array("$items->card_verify_id", "$items->name", "$items->rarity");
    }
}
return $commons;
}
print_r(getrarity());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `in_array` doesn't take an array as the first argument.  You can simply filter and check if `card_verify_id` is in `$card`.  Decoding as an array:

```
$cards = json_decode($json, true)['cards'];
$commons = array_filter($cards,
                        function($v) use($card) {
                            return in_array($v['card_verify_id'], $card);
                        });
```

Decoding as an object:

```
$cards = json_decode($json)->cards;
$commons = array_filter($cards,
                        function($v) use($card) {
                            return in_array($v->card_verify_id, $card);
                        });
```